# Attribute on options parameter with JSDoc in WebStorm: "Unresolved variable"

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, webstorm, jsdoc

I have a function with jsdoc comment that resembles the following in my code:

```javascript
/**
 * Foo function
 * @param {Object} [options]
 * @param {String} [options.foo]
 */
var foo = function (options) {
    if (!options) options = {};
    var foo = options.foo || 'foo';
    // ...
};
```

My IDE, WebStorm, marks `options.foo` as an 'unresolved variable'. If I remove the jsdoc comment, the warning disappears. How do I document this function in a way that WebStorm gets the hint and no longer displays this warning?

[image: screenshot]

Things that I tried:

- Remove `@param {String} [options.foo]`
- `@param {?String} [options.foo]`
- `@param {String} options.foo`
- `if (!options) options = {foo: 'bar'};`
- The last two combined.

Is this a bug or am I missing something? WebStorm does seem to understand the `options.foo` param definition, because `if (!options) options = {foo: 42};` raises a warning that the assigned type is not a String.

I'm using WebStorm 7.0.

Comment: use `{*}` instead of `{Object}`
```
@param {*} [options]
```

Answer (score 5):

Webstorm's documentation links to jsdoc 3. With jsdoc 3, I would document your object like this:

```
@param {{foo: string}} options
```

The way you were trying to do it implies a function signature like `function (options, options.foo)`.

Information about how to document types is available [here](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html).

Comment: doesn't work in WebStorm 7.0.1 as well. But seems to work in upcoming 7.0.3 (checked in daily builds)