# How to prevent unresolved variable message in IDE (WebStorm) from JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json, webstorm

Given the following JSON file:

**example.json**

```
{
  "labels": [
    {
      "AB": {
        "title": "example title",
        "desc": "example description"
      }
    },
    {
      "CD": {
        "title": "another example title",
        "desc": "another example description"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

It can be used in a function:

```
const jsonData = require('./example.json');
export default function() {
  const labels = jsonData.labels;
  const entries = labels[0]['AB'].title; // Unresolved variable title
}
```

The code works in the application.

However, it seems that the IDE doesn't recognise that that title key exists in the JSON file.

Is it possible to layout the JSON files structure so the IDE knows what keys to expect?

Comment: It seems that something like [JSDoc namespaces](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-namespace.html) does mark some keys as valid when applied correct. But how to add it?

Comment: Your code probably should be `const entries = labels[0]['AB'].title`

Comment: Has no effect. In whatever way I format the structure, the message keep showing. [This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20235179/attribute-on-options-parameter-with-jsdoc-in-webstorm-unresolved-variable) is related, but not quite the same. I'm not defining parameters, but using variables.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is way to structure your JSON so WebStorm "connects" the two. What about this - `const entries = labels[0]['AB']['title'];` ?

Comment: in that "labels" endpoin you have array "labels = jsonData.labels".. so if you need select item from array you  have to apply with index see @Pointy -s answer

Comment: True story @Pointy, have updated.

Comment: Added it. Still, if it's a separate file, it doesn't recognize the key. The code works, but it still gives the warning.